# Relation to ∇f(x)⋅x and laplacian

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, inner-products, laplacian

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
Proof that:

If $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$$(\nabla f(x),x)\leq 0                $$

where (,) is the scalar product

$\Rightarrow \Delta f(0)\leq 0$ (where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian).

I've been thinking about the definition of $ \Delta f = \nabla \cdot \nabla f $.
But the $(\nabla f(x),x)$ is different from $\nabla f$ , so if I try to $\nabla \cdot (\nabla f(x),x)$ I have different results... I think I miss some properties of Laplacian or of $\nabla f$.

Comment: Where does $A$ enter in to your question?

Comment: Sorry just copied the text and forgot to fix it

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried in the body of the question?

Comment: I added the part, but it's at the beginning my problem

Comment: I added the pde tag to your post, and removed the analysis tag.  Hope this is OK.  Change it back if not.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Herein I use $v \cdot w$ for $(v, w)$ with $v, w \in \Bbb R^n$.

If

$\nabla^2 f(0) > 0, \tag 1$

then since $f(x) \in C^2(\Bbb R^n)$, there is a closed ball $B(\epsilon, 0) = \{z \in \Bbb R^n \mid \Vert z \Vert \le \epsilon \}$ of radius $\epsilon > 0$, centered at $0$, such that for $y \in B(\epsilon, 0)$,

$\nabla^2f(y) > 0; \tag 2$

we donote the spherical surface, or boundary, of this ball by $S(\epsilon, 0)$.  Then by the divergence theorem,

$\displaystyle \int_{S(\epsilon, 0)} \nabla f \cdot \vec n \; dS = \int_{B(\epsilon,0)}\nabla^2 f(y) \; dV > 0, \tag 2$

by (1), where $\vec n$ is the outward-pointing unit normal vector field on $S(\epsilon, 0)$.  (2) clearly forces

$\nabla f(y) \cdot \vec n(y) > 0 \tag 3$

somewhere on $S(\epsilon, 0)$. But then

$\nabla f(y) \cdot y = \nabla f(y) \cdot \Vert y \Vert \vec n(y) = \Vert y \Vert \nabla(y) \cdot \vec n(y) > 0, \tag 4$

contradicting the hypothesis

$\nabla f(x) \cdot x \le 0 \tag 5$

we have placed upon $f(x)$.  Thus (1) cannot hold; we have instead

$\nabla^2 f(0) \le 0. \tag 6$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think it is possible to avoid the divergence theorem in the demonstration?

Comment: @LorDau:  I'm  not sure, it might be proved using the fact that $\nabla^2f(0) > 0 \Longrightarrow$ at least one eigenvalue of $\nabla \nabla f(0)$ is positive.  But using the divergence theorem is probably easier. Not sure, though.

Comment: I'm trying thinking this solution with eigenvalues. If I call $\lambda_1,---\lambda_n$ the eigenvalues, because H the hessian of f is a simmetric matrix (conseguence of the Schwarz theorem because f $\in C^2$) I have that $\Delta f(0)=\lambda_1+ --- +\lambda_n$. But I can't connect this with $(\nabla f(x),x)$ . Still thinking

Comment: @LorDau:. I doubt an eigenvalue argument will fly here, *sans* further assumptions on $f$, specifically that $0$ is  critical for $f(x)$, i.e., that $\nabla f(0) = 0$.  If that were true, then a Taylor series expansion of $f(x)$ at $0$ will have no first order terms, so the second derivatives of $f(x)$ will dominate and then $\nabla^2f(0) > 0$, implying as it does the existence of a positive eigenvalue of $\nabla \nabla f(0)$, allows the argument to proceed *via* an orthogonal change of coordinates which diagonalizes $\nabla \nabla f(0)$.

Comment: @LorDau:  you might check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449147/how-to-apply-maximum-minimum-principle-to-delta-u-u3-to-prove-uniqueness, where the type of argument I mentioned above was deployed.

Answer (score 1):

By showing that $0$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a global maximum for f. Sia x ∈ $\mathbb{R}^n$. By the mean value Theorem,
$$f(x) − f(0) = (∇f(tx), x)$$   $t\in (0,1)$.
Hence
$$ f(x) − f(0) = \frac{1}{t}(∇f(tx), tx) \leq 0 $$
Then
$$(∇f(tx), tx) ≤0$$
so $0 ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ it is a global maximum. So, as a global maximum for f, all the eigenvalues of Hessian matrix in $0$ are necessarially not positive so $λi ≤ 0 i = 1, 2 . . . n.$ 
$$\sum 
f_{xi,xi}(0) =
∆f(0) ≤ 0,$$